# Serve static files with Eve

Tags: python, flask, eve

I am running Flask and Eve on localhost  at a same time. The Flask app serves static files and makes requests to the Eve app to get some data.  I want to run Eve only, without a separate Flask app.  How can I serve static files with Eve?

Comment: whats your application

Comment: my application is simple chat+searching application using angularjs and python eve

Comment: so you need to test your application in localhost

Comment: read this http://python-eve.org/config.html

Comment: python-eve.org/config.html in this link there is no content how to serve js and css files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach will be to prefix the /api for all REST APIs.  This can be done by adding `URL_PREFIX="api"` in settings.py.

By doing this whenever there is request to /,  Eve(Flask) will not return the resource catalog instead returns the page as given in run.py.

To serve static content add route decorators accordingly in run.py,

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

Comment: I found this worked with just the URL_PREFIX and not the @app.route.  Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Eve is a Flask application (a subclass) so as a general rule everything that works with Flask works with Eve too. You could register a blueprint, or add new routes.

Also see this answer for a link to a working example: [Servicing html requests with Eve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134383/servicing-html-requests-with-eve/24134713#24134713)

Comment: you're welcome. Please accept the answer if you feel like it helped you find a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

try set import_name arg for Eve:

`app = Eve(import_name=__name__)`