# How can I generate a resource that is not associated with a field in a database?

Tags: eve

How can I generate a resource that is not associated with a field in a database?

For example, I want to know the server time, but
I do not want to connect to a database for this purpose.

such that, when a request is made to the url

http://127.0.0.1:5000/timeserver

I get server time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Eve is a Flask application all Flask tricks are available at your fingertips, such as registering a blueprint for driving custom endpoints and serving static files and/or dynamic, non-database bound endpoints.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134383/servicing-html-requests-with-eve/24134713#24134713) which contains a link to a functioning blueprint example (packaged as an Eve extension).